# Get time after boot

Tags: linux, busybox-init

When Linux is booting there are timestamps which time something was loaded etc, so I think that information about boot start time must be available. Is there a way to run in any moment command or something that shows how many seconds until boot is, like for example `10.3452232`?

It should work on busybox init system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for `/proc/uptime`.  This is inbuilt in the Linux kernel so should be available on any system.

From the manual: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html

> ```
> /proc/uptime
>           This file contains two numbers (values in seconds): the uptime
>           of the system (including time spent in suspend) and the amount
>           of time spent in the idle process.
> ```

You can read this with a simple:

```
cat /proc/uptime
```

Or in a script:

```
read uptime idle < /proc/uptime
echo $uptime
```